# Error in HTTP Post from Angular into Web API .NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, http-post

I'm trying to POST a JSON data  into a webapi from Angular 9.

Here is my POST code

```
  const headers=new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type",'application/json');
  let url:string=this.isServer?"":"https://localhost:44331/api";
  console.info(JSON.stringify(data));

  return this.client.post<any>(url+'/Crrequests',JSON.stringify(data),
  {headers,responseType:"json",withCredentials:true});
```

When I execute it triggers an error saying

> "One or more validation errors occurred"

in developer console.

But I checked with POSTMAN the same set of JSON. It works fine.

So not having an ideas whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just post the data, no need to stringify

```
return (this.client.post<any>(url + "/Crrequests", data,{ headers, responseType: "json", withCredentials: true }));
```

Replace this `JSON.stringify(data)` with `data` only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this approach might help you, this is the way I make my Http requestes to my Backend.  You could also subscribe to it and log it in the console so you can see the answer of your backend. Hope it helps

```
        var headers = new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        var url= "https://localhost:44331/api";
        return this.client.post<any>(url + "/Crrequests", 
                 {
                    //  Json object you want to post, like
                    // Email: data.email
                    // Password: data.password
                 },
                 {
                     headers
                 });
```